# Correct permissions for Windows 7 for firefox and chrome

Tags: windows-7, firefox, google-chrome, permissions

My computer has the following problem, when I start firefox the autoupdater does not work until I restart firefox with admin rights, also the Unity 3D plugin does not work if the browser is not restarted with admin rights.

With other PC's that I have, I do not need to start with admin rights manually, it does it by default.

It is APIK to have to do it manually because the notification system is a little slow when asked for admin permissions.

Is there a way to solve this? I think that a windows update cause all this mess because this wasn't like it when I first installed the applications.

Comment: What does this have to do with Chrome? :)  Have you tried reinstalling FireFox and the plug-in?

Comment: I have the same problem with Chrome, it does not autoupdate nor plugins are working

Answer (score 0):

Right click on icon of FF -> Select **Security** tab -> Select **SYSTEM** in Group or User names box -> Click on **Edit...** -> Check the check box for Full Control, Modify, Read & Execute, Read, Write. Hope this helping you.

Comment: Those are my current settings